# Using javascript variable from GWT Java

Tags: java, gwt

I have defined a javascript variable in head section of html file. E.g var yourName = "Nadeem"; Now I want to utilize this variable in my gwt java file/class/method. But it shows an error: Undefined. Please suggest some hints. Best Wishes.

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to use the right "context" where the variable is defined, i.e. `$wnd`:

```
static native String getYourName() /*-{
   return $wnd.yourName;
}-*/;
```

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#writing

Comment: It was so hard to find this solution.  I'm glad it was easier than I was imagining in my head.  Thanks!